# pass a dimentional array(2D) to a function VHDL

Tags: arrays, types, vhdl, dimensional

I declared a matrix and a signal in my TOP file like this:

```
type scanImage is array (0 to 7,0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal image_matrix : scanImage;
```

---

Now, I want to send the above signal to a function which calculates number of cells in the matrix which are not "000".

My package looks like this:

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
 use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
 use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
 USE IEEE.NUMERIC_BIT.ALL;


PACKAGE my_pack IS

type double_array is array (0 to 7,0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

--------------------square calculation declaration--------------------------
 function square_calculation(matrix : double_array) return integer;


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 function square_calculation(matrix : double_array) return integer IS
 variable tmp: integer range 0 to 64;
 begin
  tmp:=0;
  for i in 0 to 7 loop

            for j in 0 to 7 loop
                if matrix(i,j)/="000" then
                    tmp:=tmp+1;
                end if;
            end loop;

end loop;
return tmp;

end function square_calculation;


 END my_pack;
```

---

After compilizing I get this error: 
Error (10476): VHDL error at vision_ctrl.vhd(112): type of identifier "image_matrix" does not agree with its usage as "double_array" type

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: ** I must use the type declaration as above: type scanImage is array (0 to 7,0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); can't use another way

Comment: In my top I pass the matrix like that: square<=square_calculation(image_matrix);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two arrays `scanImage` and `double_array` are not the same type; just happens to be declared the same way.

So declare `image_matrix` with the type `double_array`, instead of making a new type `scanImage`:

```
signal image_matrix : my_pack.double_array;
```

Then you can use `my_pack.square_calculation` with the `image_matrix` argument.